# Electron.js + React/Redux - best practices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, electron

So, here the thing.
We have main process and renderer and they`re is isolated from each other and only bridge is IPC messages(to main process) or BrowserWindow webcontents send(to main process).

I'm handling my events in `componentDidMount` like so:

```
ipcRenderer.on('deviceWasPlugged', this.deviceWasPluggedListener);
```

And ofc I'll remove this listener with `componentWillUnount` for preventing memory leaking in case the component was destroyed:

```
ipcRenderer.removeListener('deviceWasPlugged', this.deviceWasPluggedListener);
```

Obviously I have a such method in my Class/Component

```
deviceWasPluggedListener = (e, somedata) => {
  // boring stuff goes there...
}
```

All is peachy, except one fact - It doesn't seems right as for me.
I still think, there should be a better place to keep my events listeners.

I think, I cant keep it in redux middleware, coz event based model won't allow me to unsubscribe of this events in redux middleware and multiple events will be created when I'll be trying to dispatch smth, even if I'll switch it by action.type:

```
const someMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  if (action.type === 'SOME_TYPE') {
    // ...
  }

  next(action);
};

export default someMiddleware;
```

So, guys, please tell me is there any better place to keep my backend events? It should be triggered every time I want it, and it shouldn't cause memory leaking problem with `maxEventListeners`.